# How to manage lightbox from header button of main page in wix

Tags: javascript, velo

Inherited unfinished project that has multiple pages with same header, a masterPage.js and lightbox for logging in user. The header which is shared by other pages has button to "Log in" or "Log out" depending on logged in status of user. If clicking it, it should pop up lightbox if the text on the button is "Log in" and simply log out if "Log out". I've tried to control lightbox (onClick event) from masterPage.js but seemingly it is out of scope and doesn't recognise the lightbox element id. I could link the lightbox through pages & menus, but don't know how to listen to lightbox closing and therefore update (or not) the original "Log in / out" button with text representing the potentially new status.

I'm open to the "best" way rather than build on the half finished attempt to get it working if it makes sense to do so.

Snippet example of just trying to open lightbox, but element id lightbox1 not recognised

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';
$w.onReady(function () {
$w("loginButton").onClick(() => {
wixWindow.openLightbox("lightbox1")
})
});
```

similarly this doesn't work either

```
$w("#lightbox1").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lightbox:
You can create a Lightbox by going to the editor, clicking on "Add" from the left panel, selecting "Lightbox" and then clicking on "Create Lightbox". Give it a name, e.g. "Login Lightbox".

Add Login Form to Lightbox:
Once you have created the lightbox, you can add a login form to it. You can drag and drop a login form from the left panel onto the lightbox.

Add Login Button to Header:
Add the "Log in / Log out" button to the header on your master page. You can add an onClick event to the button that will trigger the Lightbox. The code to show the lightbox would be as follows:

```
javascript
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#loginButton").onClick(() => {
    if($w("#loginButton").label === "Log in"){
      wixWindow.openLightbox("Login Lightbox");
    } else {
      //logout functionality
      //replace this with your own logout code
      $w("#loginButton").label = "Log in";
    }
  });
});
```

This code checks the label of the button. If it is "Log in", it opens the Lightbox. If it is "Log out", it logs the user out and changes the label back to "Log in".

Handle Login and Logout:
To handle the login and logout functionality, you can add an onSubmit event to the login form in the Lightbox. The code to handle the login would be something like this:

```
javascript
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#loginForm").onSubmit((event) => {
    let email = $w("#inputEmail").value;
    let password = $w("#inputPassword").value;
    wixUsers.login(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        //replace this with your own success code
        $w("#loginButton").label = "Log out";
        wixWindow.lightbox.close();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        //replace this with your own error handling code
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
});
```

This code handles the login form submission. It gets the email and password values, and then calls the wixUsers.login() function to log the user in. If the login is successful, it changes the label of the "Log in / Log out" button to "Log out" and closes the lightbox. If there is an error, it logs the error to the console.

Listen to Lightbox Closing:
To update the "Log in / Log out" button label when the Lightbox is closed, you can add an onClose event to the Lightbox. The code to update the button label would be something like this:

```
perl
$w("#Login Lightbox").onClose(() => {
  if(wixUsers.currentUser.loggedIn){
    $w("#loginButton").label = "Log out";
  } else {
    $w("#loginButton").label = "Log in";
  }
});
```

This code listens to the Lightbox closing event. If the user is logged in, it changes the label of the "Log in / Log out" button to "Log out". If the user is not logged in, it changes the label back to "Log in".